# Can I make a function in python treat undefined names as strings?

Tags: python, string, function

Say I have this code

```
def shut_down(s):
  if s=='yes':
    return "Shutting down"
  else: return "whatever dude I don't even care"
```

Is there a way for it to accept a variable (not a string) and treat it as a string? In short, is `foo(undefined)`, possible?

I tried both

```
def shut_down(s):
  s=str(s)
```

and

```
def shut_down(str(s)):
```

but it doesn't work. (When I enter `shut_down(yes)` I get the error *yes is not defined*. It does work when I enter `shut_down('yes')`, but that's not the question.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be coding in a shell. Write your code in a file.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks, I guess that's true, but I'm only playing around while learning. But yeah maybe it's better to use a file.


@Blurp Sorry, badly expressed from my part, the function does work, (at least in shell¿?), but my question is if there is a way I can call it as `shut_down(yes)`, without the quotes, and make it work.

Comment: Your function works if you do something like `print(shut_down('yes')`. It's not clear what you mean by "another method". Do you want to pass in a variable that contains a string or...?

Comment: @Blurp, yes, my question basically is "Can I enter an object (not a string) in a function and that it treats it as a string?"

Comment: I don't understand... how would it work without the quotes? If you store the string a variable like `answer = 'yes'`, then you can call the function like `shut_down(answer)`.

Comment: Oh woah I just saw the title of my question and it's so wrong. I'm too tired, will go to sleep and try again tomorrow maybe

Comment: @Blurp So you're confirming there is no way to make it work, right? Thanks. Then I guess the best way to do a something like this would be using `input()`. Good night!

Comment: No, I'm not confirming that. It certainly is possible to pass _any_ variable to a function and treat it as string. You might need to provide more detail about how it "doesn't work".

Comment: @Blurp Well, I get _name 'yes' is not defined_. I guess `yes` is not a variable, it isn't actually anything as it isn't defined, but can I make it to be accepted as a string? In short, is `foo(undefined)` posible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. There's no reason why it should be possible. If you want it to be a string, make it a string.

Comment: Thanks @Rawing. Yeah, I thought so, I was just a bit confused because of how codecademy worded the exercise. I have changed now to datacamp tough, which I'm liking much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. If you want to enter a string, do so, use `shut_down('yes')`, with the quotes.

You might also prefer to write the next

```
def shut_down():
  s=input("Shut down? ").lower()
  if s=='yes':
    return "Shutting down"
  else: return "whatever dude I don't even care"
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and the input method saved me.